# Sql syntax error - expecting ( or as

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error

I am trying to write this SQL code:

```
create table Users
{
    UserID int primary key identity(200,1),
    FirstName varchar(20) not null,
    LastName varchar(20) not null,
    BirthDate dateTime not null,
    HomeTown varchar(30),
    WorkPlace varchar(40),
    Email not null
}
```

The problem is that next the `{` symbol, I get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near '{'.

When my mouse over the sign it adds:

> Expecting '(' or AS

In addition, I also get an error on the values that are in the bracket

> Incorrect syntax near '20'. Expecting '(' or Select".

The thing is that I have another SQL document (that I didn't write) and the same syntax work there! Why is that and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS you're using. MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.?

Comment: The SQL Validator is an excellent on-line tool for checking ANSI SQL syntax, http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need brackets not braces - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp Also a data type for email

I.e.

```
create table Users
(
UserID int primary key identity(200,1),
FirstName varchar(20) not null,
LastName varchar(20) not null,
BirthDate dateTime not null,
HomeTown varchar(30),
WorkPlace varchar(40),
Email varchar(40) not null
)
```

Comment: the email column is missing the datatype

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the `datatype` for `Email` columnn.
Use ()instead of {}.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql statement should look like the following one, first change the {} to () then added the datatype to your email column

```
create table Users (
UserID int primary key identity(200,1),
FirstName varchar(20) not null,
LastName varchar(20) not null,
BirthDate dateTime not null,
HomeTown varchar(30),
WorkPlace varchar(40),
[Email] varchar(255) not null
)
```

Comment: And use " instead of [.  (ANSI SQL,  since no dbms specified.)